# Winxp Workgroup wireless

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

I need to create closed network for few computers running Windows XP connected to wireless router. Can some one give me some pointers?

I configured the routers wifi and security, set device ip to 192.168.0.1 and dhcp range of 5 addresses (192.168.0.100-104). Computers connect to my wifi network and can ping router but can't see each other in network. I turned on file and printer sharing and shared appropriate folders and set permissions. I added all computers ( with unique names ) to the same workgroup called ABC and restarted them. They should see each other now but they don't, nor I can ping them  (I did this same setup with 5 pc running Windows 7 and they immediately showed on HomeGroup so now I can't figure out what is wrong with this). Firewall is disabled and router is tested and configuration ok.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Sounds like you've covered most of the basics in your question. Check to see if the computer browsing service is running. You may also want to check this Microsoft KB article out - [You cannot view other workgroup computers on the network on a Windows XP-based computer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/903267).